# C# Disposing last TabPage setting select the first

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, dispose, tabpage

I noticed that when I `Dispose()` the last `TabPage` of a `TabControl` it's automatically set selected the **first**.

In my case i have a class `FormTab` which contains within it the *"index"* of the tab in `TabPag` and all of this form are a `MDIChild`.

Is there any way to set what the next `TabPage` must be selected, for example the **second-last**?

After `Dispose()` it's evoked the event `SelectedIndexChanged` and inside `tabControlForm.SelectedTab` is already the first `TabPage`, so this is the code

```
private void tabControlForm_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var form in MdiChildren)
    {
        var childForm = (FormTab) form;
        //Check for its corresponding MDI child form
        if (childForm.TabPag.Equals(tabControlForm.SelectedTab))
        {
            //Activate the MDI child form
            childForm.Select();
        }
    }
}
```

`Dispose()` event on class `TabForm`

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
        //Destroy the corresponding Tabpage when closing MDI child form
        if (tabPag != null)
        {
            tabPag.Dispose();
            if(!tabCtrl.HasChildren)
                tabCtrl.Visible = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you the one doing the `Dispose()`ing?

Comment: @lc. - Yes, I call it via a button

Comment: What happens if you select the tab you want to be selected before disposing the other?

Comment: @Pikoh - The `Dispose()` is invoked when the **Form** `FormTab` will close. I edited my post adding the code of `Dispose()`